# Mule - http post message

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I need to make some http post calls towards external systems.
I have a simple question, I want to send via post an xml file that is not the payload itself, but just a part of it. I can retrieve it easily with `#[payload.getMyXmlPostMessage()]`, but how to put this information on the http component?
I don't want to overwrite the payload that contains other informations that will be used later on the flow.

Comment: Do you need the response of that post to become the new payload or it can be done in parallel?

Comment: The response of the new payload should enrich the old one. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way to invoke an external service without changing the payload is by delegating to a separate flow.

You can invoke it using the VM transport, setting the exchange patter to request response.

This way the payload will be copied, you can use the new flow to make all the changes you might need and the result will be stored in the var you configured within the `<enricher />`

Comment: Thank you, I ended up thinking at the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Different options are there to call external service without modifying the existing payload :-

1. Save your existing payload in a variable just before the Http call, and later set the payload from the variable using set payload just after the Http call
2. Use an Async block in the flow and call the external service using Http there. Using Async block will create a copy of the thread and will not disturb the current payload, as it will get a copy of that.
3. And off course the Enricher component is there and you can use your Http component inside the Enricher and call the external service. As you know, the Enricher will not disturb the current payload.